# how to let an application called by Runtime.exec() "take over" the console until it's finished?

Tags: java, command-line

in my code i use 7z command line to extract an archive

```
 public static void extract() {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process pr = rt.exec("7za x -o"+ tempFolderStr +" "+sourceStr);
        pr.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out("Error extracting " + sourceStr);
        quit();
    }

    //if tempFolder doesn't exists 7zip failed to extract for whatever reason
    tempFolder = new File(tempFolderStr);

    if (!tempFolder.exists()){
        out("Error extracting " + sourceStr);
        quit();
    }

    source = tempFolder;
}
```

however in case of large archives that take a while it may not be obvious to the user if it's just the exctracting operations or if it's my own application that hanged up (aside from extraction there's plenty of other stuff to do before the user gets prompted to do anything again), plus the extraction itself may pause, say because the archive is password protected or what else

for this reason i'd want 7zip to "take over" the console and show its progress output, prompts and whatnot until it finishes and then gives the console back to my application, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder` and `.inheritIO()`:

```
final List<String> command = Arrays.asList(
    "7za", "x", "-o", tempFolder, sourceStr
);

final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO();

final int retcode = pb.start().waitFor();
```

etc etc